# Media Recording for ever

Tags: android, activerecord, media-player, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I am developing an application for voice recording... the problem is that I dont know how to make it work in the background. I mean even if the user close the application the recorder keeps working.. and if it reaches the max.. it delete the file and record again..

The user only should press the button once and the application should work forever till the user uninstall the program.

My code is the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private MediaRecorder recorder ;

Button B ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();

    B = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1) ;

      B.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {

               Thread startThread = new Thread ( new startRe (recorder));
               startThread.start() ; 
               B.setEnabled(false); 

           }
      }
      );


}
}
```

The Recording class:

```
public class startRe implements Runnable {
private MediaRecorder recorder;


startRe( MediaRecorder r ) {

    this.recorder = r ; 
}
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    startRecording();
}


public void startRecording() {
    //recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(getFilePath());
    try{
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


private String getFilePath() {
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filePath, "MediaRecorderSample");

    if(!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs();

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp4");
}
```

}

The problem now is how to make it forever and how to delete it when it reaches the max 
size. 
Also, using this code I dont know if it is really recording or not because I couldn't find the output file..

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by starting the recording in a Service and calling startService().
This way the recording will go on even if the Activity that started called startService() is closed.